# Bash: how to copy directory's files if present

Tags: bash, cp

In as script I have the statement

```
eval cp "$chapter"/subsections/* $temp/subsections
```

However, I am not sure there are actually files in "$chapter"/subsections/. As a consequence I get errors :

```
cp: cannot stat `Commissioning/subsections/*': No such file or directory
```

Is there an option in cp to avoid complaints (I couldn't find any) ?

Is there a simple way to check existence of any file in a directory ?

Comment: What's with the `eval`? It is a completely superfluous complication here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really `cp` complaining. When you use wildcards like `*`, the shell replaces them with the complete list of all matching files. When no files match, it just leaves the `*`, telling `cp` to copy file named `*`.

You can use the following trick instead:

```
cp -r "${chapter}"/subsections/. "${temp}"/subsections
```

Now you will be passing the whole directory to `cp`, with request to copy it recursively. And since you are referring to it through `.`, `cp` won't copy its name but only the contents.

Comment: What would be the difference between what you suggest and just doing `cp -r "${chapter}"/subsections "${temp}"/subsections` ?

Comment: If `"${temp}"/subsections` existed, your command will create a `"${temp}"/subsections/subsections`.